# problems with widget's size in gtk box gtk

Tags: c, gtk3

for some reason button expands fully from up to bottom, but *fill* and *expand* are set to false, so it shouldn't be the case, right?

[this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx6cY.png)

and code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main() {
    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* box;
    GtkWidget* frame;
        
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 400);

    frame = gtk_frame_new("box");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame), box);

    GtkWidget* button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("test");

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(button, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(button, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
}
```

forcing widget size with gtk_widget_set_size_request only affects the button's width.